# What is the different between getRefreshToken() to iid().getToken() in Firebase?

Tags: firebase, react-native, push-notification

I have a question about firebase... recently I see that

```
app.messaging().getRefreshToken()
```

didn't call every time and I understand why but if I want anyway to call it every time. so calling to

```
app.iid().getToken()
```

is equivalent to getRefreshToken()?

If not what is the different between them?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I don't see the `getRefreshToken()` in the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User#refreshToken) but the below explanation should help.

`getToken(forceRefresh)`: `getToken` method returns a **JWT** token to identify the user.

It returns the **current token** if it has not **expired**, otherwise this will **refresh the token** and return a **new one**.

> If you use `forceRefresh: true`, it will always return a *refreshed token regardless of expiration*.

`app.iid().getToken(true)` will fetch the refreshed token.